Ubuntu dotnet: Could not load file or assembly 'X, Version=1.0.18.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified
I've been working with dotnet on Ubuntu. I created a lot of microservices all of them working.
Now I came to this error in this specific microservice which the error is not obvious. It's related to a nuget library I have which is imported, which it is also part of other nuget libraries, but as far as I know all of them are using version 1.0.20 of that library.
In my understanding this error is related to the TappCommon 1.0.18.0 dll which it can't find. These are all in the nuget directory. Although I don't want to use this version (as I said the libraries reference version 1.0.20) I need to know how and where is this being referencing. So I need to debug this on linux/Ubuntu.
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Local
AppSettingsFile=appsettings.json
AppSettingsFile=appsettings.Local.json
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[6]
      Application startup exception
      Could not load file or assembly 'TappCommon, Version=1.0.18.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
      
      System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
      Could not load file or assembly 'TappCommon, Version=1.0.18.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
      
         at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
         at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.AssemblyPart.get_Types()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFeatureProvider.PopulateFeature(IEnumerable`1 parts, ControllerFeature feature)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateFeature[TFeature](TFeature feature)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetControllerTypes()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetDescriptors()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ActionDescriptorProviderContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.UpdateCollection()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.Initialize()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointDataSourceBase.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Subscribe>b__0()
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.ChangeTokenRegistration`1..ctor(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action`1 changeTokenConsumer, TState state)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.OnChange(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action changeTokenConsumer)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointDataSourceBase.Subscribe()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ControllerActionEndpointDataSource..ctor(ControllerActionEndpointDataSourceIdProvider dataSourceIdProvider, IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actions, ActionEndpointFactory endpointFactory, OrderedEndpointsSequenceProvider orderSequence)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.GetOrCreateDataSource(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapControllers(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
         at Notification.WebApi.Startup.<>c.<Configure>b__7_1(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints) in /home/abel/Projects/TappEngine/LiveInvesting/Notification/Presentation/Notification.WebApi/Startup.cs:line 134
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRoutingApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseEndpoints(IApplicationBuilder builder, Action`1 configure)
         at Notification.WebApi.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in /home/abel/Projects/TappEngine/LiveInvesting/Notification/Presentation/Notification.WebApi/Startup.cs:line 132
         at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
         at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IApplicationBuilder app)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'TappCommon, Version=1.0.18.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
      
      File name: 'TappCommon, Version=1.0.18.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
Unhandled exception. System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load file or assembly 'TappCommon, Version=1.0.18.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.AssemblyPart.get_Types()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFeatureProvider.PopulateFeature(IEnumerable`1 parts, ControllerFeature feature)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateFeature[TFeature](TFeature feature)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetControllerTypes()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetDescriptors()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ActionDescriptorProviderContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.UpdateCollection()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointDataSourceBase.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Subscribe>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.ChangeTokenRegistration`1..ctor(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action`1 changeTokenConsumer, TState state)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.OnChange(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action changeTokenConsumer)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointDataSourceBase.Subscribe()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ControllerActionEndpointDataSource..ctor(ControllerActionEndpointDataSourceIdProvider dataSourceIdProvider, IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actions, ActionEndpointFactory endpointFactory, OrderedEndpointsSequenceProvider orderSequence)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.GetOrCreateDataSource(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapControllers(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
   at Notification.WebApi.Startup.<>c.<Configure>b__7_1(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints) in /home/abel/Projects/TappEngine/LiveInvesting/Notification/Presentation/Notification.WebApi/Startup.cs:line 134
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRoutingApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseEndpoints(IApplicationBuilder builder, Action`1 configure)
   at Notification.WebApi.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in /home/abel/Projects/TappEngine/LiveInvesting/Notification/Presentation/Notification.WebApi/Startup.cs:line 132
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at Notification.WebApi.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/abel/Projects/TappEngine/LiveInvesting/Notification/Presentation/Notification.WebApi/Program.cs:line 9
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'TappCommon, Version=1.0.18.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

File name: 'TappCommon, Version=1.0.18.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'


So how can we help u? U tell us that u understood the problem and have no questions just the statement that "So I need to debug this on linux/Ubuntu.". I agree with u that u should keep debugging.

Actually my micro-service was depending on a dependency "A" that was depending on "TappCommon" with version 1.0.18
Just needed to build the dependency "A" again that it automatically referenced the right version for TappCommon (1.0.20)
So this is all that was into this error, for my case.
